# Show element only when user types a value into input box which is higher than 0

Tags: javascript, html

I'm building a simple stats calculator for WoW Classic. The idea is that you choose a class, enter some values in the inputs. As each value is changed (I used change and keyup for this), the resulting 'calculations' also appear below the form. Happy I have got this far and just wanting to take it a step further now.

I am using vanilla JS and jQuery. Here is my fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/ejnLbyug/

I'd like to hide elements in the HTML if a user has left them empty. For example, as it is now, when a user leaves the 'Stamina' box empty, it still shows the result for 'Hit Points' as +0.

Instead of showing that +0, I'd rather just hide it completely if that input box is left empty. How could I do this for all the 'results' that are printed with inner.HTML? So until the user actually types in a number higher than 0 into any of the input boxes, the elements are hidden.

I have tried the following for the Stamina input for example:

```
if (stamina === 0) { return;
} else {
  document.getElementById('staminaresult').innerHTML = ('+' + stamina + ' Hit Points')
 }
```

But this doesn't seem to be working. Any ideas?

Comment: Properly indenting your code will help identify some of these issues. You're immediately returning after entering the code block `stamina === 0`

Answer (score 1):

I have tried this code on your document, and it's working, for example, one of the results I hide it

```
 if(this.intellect > 0) {
   document.getElementById('intellectresult').innerHTML = ('+' + intellect + '  Mana');
 }
```

and here I'm using `window` to get the current state after updated (this is working fine with updates)

```
    window.intellect = intellect * 15; }

    // Intellect - mana result
    if(window.intellect > 0) {
       return document.getElementById('intellectresult').innerHTML = ('+' + 
        window.intellect + '  Mana');
    }
```

but you need to add this condition to every `document.innerHTML`, and I saw that's not good, try to make the code shorter

Comment: Hi, this does successfully hide the element at the start. But then when the user types a number greater than 0 into the box it does not show the element.

Comment: I update the answer, check update, you will share it on `window`

Comment: Hey Soliman, thanks very much for your help. One last thing - I don’t understand where you have put the code above. Could you share me a fiddle with your implementation of the code?